# Open Stack Installation - single server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, openstack

I have managed to set up openstack on a single machine, everything appears to work with exception to being able to ssh.

I can ssh to the instance from the host box, which has a public ip. However as soon as I try and ssh from the same network as the public ip the ssh goes and logs in to the host box and not the virtual instance.

im pretty sure ive missed something but cant put my finger on it

Mat

Answer (score 0):

Are you using quantum or nova-network?  is this essex or folsom or maybe even grizzly?

My guess is, you've setup a public ip resource pool that is conflicting an IP assigned to your single server openstack deployment.  If that IP is assigned to physical interface on the physical host, any service listening on 0.0.0.0 will be listening on that IP ( this would likely be the case for ssh ).

If you intend to share a single public IP with both your openstack cloud and your physical host, I recommend performing NAT beyond the edge of that physical node.